# Substituir mapa do Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Minha dúvida é como utilizar a biblioteca google maps com um outro mapa, ou imagem.

Encontrei um exemplo interessante que me deixou pensativo, mas não consegui encontrar uma resposta até o momento.

Este é o exemplo: http://pwmap.ru/pwi/

E algumas imagens:

[image: Interactive map for Perfect World Online game]

[image: Interactive map for Perfect World Online game - Zoom baixo]

Já vi outro exemplo com mapas de jogos, como o do GTA, alguém poderia me explicar, ou me indicar um site ou tutorial que mostre algo sobre o assunto? Pois na documentação da biblioteca não consegui encontrar como se faz isso.

Grato,

Comment: Dê uma olhada no http://openlayers.org/.

Comment: Eu acessei o site, e é realmente isso que queria, mas agora surgiu outro "problema", como eu gero os tiles a partir de uma imagem grande que tenho no meu computador, eu encontrei um programa, o maptiler, mas com a versão free dele só tem 2 niveis de zoom e enche meu mapa com o logo deles, há algum outro programa pra fazer isso? E uma dúvida, como eu defino minhas próprias coordenadas nessa imagem?

Comment: Jean, se o openlayers resolveu esta parte do problema (o que foi colocado na pergunta), te aconselho a criar outra pergunta, agora mais específica, com todos estes novos detalhes e dúvidas. Para saber mais sobre perguntas-camaleão: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1901/essa-pergunta-pode-ser-considerada-uma-pergunta-camale%C3%A3o. PS: Vou incluir uma resposta com o openlayres pra constar aqui.

Comment: Existe a [sobreposição de solo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#GroundOverlays) do próprio Google Maps, neste caso, utilizando imagens. [Aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) tem um exemplo.

Comment: Jean Carlo dá uma olhada na minha resposta abaixo, clicando em "Executar trecho de código" e depois em "Página toda", porque o @Bruno César conseguiu incluir o snippet, então agora tem um exemplo completo e verificável. Btw, dá uma olhada na solução que o Paulo indicou, que parece ser interessante, mas não sei se é free.

Comment: gustavox, o exemplo abaixo resolve parte do problema, sobre a api dos maps, mas como gerar as imagens do mapa, tenho um mapa bem grande aqui, e não sei gerar os arquivos no formato necessário pra utilizar no openlayers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que utilizar a biblioteca do google maps com outra imagem não seja possível, mas existem algumas ferramentas semelhantes que podem ajudar, como [`openLayers`](http://openlayers.org/) que é free, e dispõe de recursos bastante avançados.

[Neste link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/) você encontra alguns exemplos do que pode ser feito com ele. [A documentação](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/doc/) parece ser bem completa (em inglês), e não parece muito difícil de implementar.

Veja este exemplo, utilizado no [*quick start*](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/doc/quickstart.html):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```